# Can I use the same adapter for two different listviews in different activities?

Tags: java, android

I want to set two activities with one listview on each. To do it i've designed my own xml file for it's design, and so the listview has different textviews and images. But i'd like to use the same adapter on both listviews.

That's my java file of the carnes activity.

```
public class Carnes extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView lvItems;
    private Adapter adaptador;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_carnes);

        lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_carnes);
        adaptador = (Adapter) new Adaptador(this, GetArrayItems());
        lvItems.setAdapter((ListAdapter) adaptador);
    }

    private ArrayList<Entidad> GetArrayItems() {
        ArrayList<Entidad> listItems = new ArrayList<>();
        listItems.add(new Entidad(R.drawable.calabacines_3, "Lomo", " 5 min.", 5, R.drawable.color_carnes));
        listItems.add(new Entidad(R.drawable.patatas_deluxe_especiadas_70523_300_150, "Pollo", " 20 min.", 4, R.drawable.color_carnes));
        listItems.add(new Entidad(R.drawable.tomate, "Pavo", " 1 min.", 3, R.drawable.color_carnes));

        return listItems;
    }
}
```

Here it is my Adapter:

```
public class Adaptador extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Entidad> listItems;

    public Adaptador(Context context, ArrayList<Entidad> listItems) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listItems = listItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Entidad Item = (Entidad) getItem(position);

        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.elemento_lista, null);
        ImageView imgFoto = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgFoto);
        TextView tvTitulo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitulo);
        TextView tvTiempo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTiempo);
        RatingBar calificacion = (RatingBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBarVerd);
        ImageView colorfondo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.colorfondo);


        imgFoto.setImageResource(Item.getImgFoto());
        tvTitulo.setText(Item.getTitulo());
        tvTiempo.setText(Item.getTiempo());
        calificacion.setRating(Item.getRating());
        colorfondo.setImageResource(Item.getColorfondo());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

And i leave you the other activity which uses the same Adapter below (remember it's a different listview):

```
public class Verduras extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView lvItems;
    private Adapter adaptador;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_verduras);

        lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_verduras);
        adaptador = (Adapter) new Adaptador(this, GetArrayItems());
        lvItems.setAdapter((ListAdapter) adaptador);
    }

    private ArrayList<Entidad> GetArrayItems() {
        ArrayList<Entidad> listItems = new ArrayList<>();
        listItems.add(new Entidad(R.drawable.calabacines_3, "Calabacines", " 10 min.", 4, R.drawable.color_verduras));
        listItems.add(new Entidad(R.drawable.patatas_deluxe_especiadas_70523_300_150, "Patatas", " 15 min.", 2, R.drawable.color_verduras));
        listItems.add(new Entidad(R.drawable.tomate, "Tomates", " 2 min.", 5, R.drawable.color_verduras));

        return listItems;
    }
}
```

And that's what i've used to define the variables:

```
public class Entidad {

    private int imgFoto;
    private String titulo;
    private String tiempo;
    private int ratingBar;
    private int colorfondo;

    public Entidad(int imgFoto, String titulo, String tiempo, int ratingBar, int colorfondo) {

        this.imgFoto = imgFoto;
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.tiempo = tiempo;
        this.ratingBar = ratingBar;
        this.colorfondo = colorfondo;
    }

    public int getImgFoto() {
        return imgFoto;
    }

    public String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }

    public String getTiempo() {
        return tiempo;
    }

    public int getRating() { return ratingBar; }

    public int getColorfondo() {
        return colorfondo;
    }
}
```

What it happens is that the code looks like it's OK, but when you run the app, then it suddenly stops without telling you what happende.

Thanks for helping and if you need anything else just tell me.

That's what appears onthe logcat.

```
05-29 16:08:38.173 2247-2247/com.test.platos4 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060059
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1013)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getValue(ResourcesWrapper.java:209)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:331)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:198)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:191)
        at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:102)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:86)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:94)
        at com.test.platos4.Adaptador.getView(Adaptador.java:62)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2271)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1769)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:733)
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1622)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2106)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1868)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1689)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4214)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-29 16:08:38.183 1379-1571/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.test.platos4/.Carnes
05-29 16:08:38.323 1379-1571/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 658K, 12% free 22447K/25415K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
05-29 16:08:38.323 1379-1571/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.test.platos4/.Dishes
05-29 16:08:38.413 1121-1621/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 1114112
05-29 16:08:38.853 1379-1392/system_process W/ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{a78e7c78 com.test.platos4/.Carnes}
05-29 16:08:39.403 1121-1456/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 1114112
05-29 16:08:39.663 1121-1456/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 1114112
05-29 16:08:48.043 1379-1392/system_process W/ActivityManager: Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
    Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{a78e7c78 com.test.platos4/.Carnes}
05-29 16:08:48.863 1379-1392/system_process W/ActivityManager: Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{a7ce95d0 com.test.platos4/.Menu}
05-29 16:08:58.043 1379-1392/system_process W/ActivityManager: Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{a7ce7888 com.test.platos4/.Dishes}
    Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{a78e7c78 com.test.platos4/.Carnes}
05-29 16:09:00.013 1440-1440/com.android.systemui D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb8af20d0: ver 2 0
```

Comment: JavaScript isn't the same as Java, just because it has Java in the name. Please don't tag with JS when you're referring to Java

Comment: If it suddenly stops, then there must some crash due to exception. Check the errolog in logcat. and do post it here.

Comment: I've added what you wanted @LostGeek

Comment: this is simply says you have troubles with layout elemento_lista file. put the breakpoint in getview in all line and see where it crashes.  either layout doesn't exists, or its childids have issues.

Comment: But why does it work properly when i emulate the verduras activity and it doesn't when i load the other? @LostGeek

Comment: ok,,it crashed in line no. 62, tell me in Adaptador , which was that line ?

Answer (score 0):

In your code your not using the same adapter, you are instantiating a new adapter in both your `Activities` like: `new Adaptador(...)`

Here´s a [tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-a-BaseAdapter-with-ListView) on Using a BaseAdapter with ListView,

Here´s a snipe from the tutorial showing how `getView()` should work:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // inflate the layout for each list row
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).
                inflate(R.layout.layout_list_view_row_items, parent, false);
        }

        // get current item to be displayed
        Item currentItem = (Item) getItem(position);

        // get the TextView for item name and item description
        TextView textViewItemName = (TextView) 
            convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_item_name);
        TextView textViewItemDescription = (TextView) 
            convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_item_description);

        //sets the text for item name and item description from the current item object
        textViewItemName.setText(currentItem.getItemName());
        textViewItemDescription.setText(currentItem.getItemDescription());

        // returns the view for the current row
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

> To optimize the listview's performance, a new row layout should be
>   inflated only when convertView == null. This is because the adapter's
>   getView method is called whenever the listview needs to show a new row
>   on the screen. The convertView gets recycled in this process. Hence,
>   the row layout should be inflated just once when convertView == null,
>   and it contents should be updated on subsequent getView calls, instead
>   of inflating a new row on each call which is very expensive.

I would also like to suggest using [RecyclerView insted of ListView](https://www.truiton.com/2015/03/android-recyclerview-vs-listview-comparison/). `RecyclerView` was created to solve many problems that `ListView` had/has..